# can't download file using webforms' HttpHandler

Tags: c#, webforms, httphandler

I use HttpHandler to download file from webforms aspx page. Everything is ok if the name of the file has no commas. If it has - I get an error (Could not find file on server). 
This is the code of HttpHandler for downloading files:

```
public class DocDownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int npId = int.Parse(context.Request["npId"]);
        string fileName = context.Request["fileName"];
        fileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileName);
        string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocsDir"].Trim('\\') + "\\" + npId + "\\" + fileName;

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data1, 0, data1.Length);

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(data1);

            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to download files with commas at their names and could be other signs invoking the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding the resource path before submitting it to the WebClient:

```
string fileURI = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filePath);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(fileURI))
{
    ...
}
```